# Error in installing in Hellinger distance library with the help of github

Tags: github, installation, scikit-learn, tree, site-packages

While trying to use hellinger-distance-criterion from github link https://github.com/EvgeniDubov/hellinger-distance-criterion

I am not able to find some error.

In the github link, it is given the following steps:

> You will need a cython "header" file (.pxd) from sklearn.
>
> In case you've installed sklearn from source code package, you've
> already got it.
>
> In case you've installed sklearn using pip install sklearn then you
> need to get it.
>
> Got to
> https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/tree
> Download _criterion.pxd and place it your local sklearn installation
> folder Linux usually at
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/tree Windows usually at
> C:\Users[user
> name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\

I have already installed sklearn from source code package in my Jupyter notebook. I have checked in local system and virtual environment.

Then I copied hellinger_distance_criterion.pyx in my local system and checked it in my jupyter notebook.

After that I was running following code as suggested in the github link https://github.com/EvgeniDubov/hellinger-distance-criterion for setup

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    name='hellinger-distance-criterion',
    version=0.1,
    url='github.com/EvgeniDubov/hellinger-distance-criterion',
    author='Evgeni Dubov',
    author_email='evgeni.dubov@gmail.com',
    ext_modules=cythonize("hellinger_distance_criterion.pyd"),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

I got following error

```
ValueError: 'hellinger_distance_criterion.pyd' doesn't match any files
```

Please help me out to solve this error

Comment: The instructions from GitHub continue and show `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` should be run.  Did you do that step?

Comment: Where I need to run this step?

Comment: After cloning the repo (or downloading/expanding the ZIP file), I think all the steps in the [Build](https://github.com/EvgeniDubov/hellinger-distance-criterion#build) instructions need to be followed.  The "following code as suggested" you mentioned should be run as the instructions show, `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.